# How to force root categories to be collapsed by default when adding new product on Magento 1.7

Tags: magento-1.7

Is it possible to have the category tree collapsed when adding new products?

Now the root categories are expanded.

Subcategories are collapsed (this is ok).

How to force root categories to be collapsed by default?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Problem solved! In /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit/categories.phtml there is a commented line "//tree.expandAll();". Change that line with tree.collapseAll();  Make sure you don't comment the new added line.

Comment: Answer yourself in answer and then accept it so the question will appear as answered for others. See here for more: http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit/categories.p‌​html there is a commented line "//tree.expandAll();". Change that line with tree.collapseAll();

Make sure you don't comment the new added line.